# Give user customization choice

Tags: web-services, web-applications, web

I've seen that this site allows users to customize their questions through some marks (headers with **.  Underlined..... Bold...)
So how to do this .
Here is what I know: html- php-javascript-ruby:
Is it possible to obtain this with my knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are open source javascript markdown processors. like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) or [that one](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown)